# Run Time Error 5 when Running the macro from a shared drive

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

The following code runs perfectly from my desktop or other folder paths. Except in a shared drive that keeps giving me a run-time error 5

The error appears on the following line

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Cell & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

The full code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ReportSheet As Worksheet 

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover Page").Range("F11").Value <> vbNullString Then
FormatDate = Format(Sheets("Cover Page").Range("F11"), "MMMM DD, YYYY")

End If

Cell = "Statements - " & FormatDate

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", " Sheet2", " Sheet3”).Select 

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Cell & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Application.Goto Reference:=Sheets("X").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: If you do Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Cell & "'.pdf"    is the path malformed at all?

Comment: Is this a mapped drive, a UNC path (\\servername\etc) or a (eg) Sharepoint path (`https://etc`) ?

Comment: Hey Allen, I'm not sure I follow you. The path is not malformed, it's on a shared drive. My other macros work perfectly in the same path, but not this one

Comment: @Tim Williams it is a mapped drive, with a server name

Comment: In that case, you might have better luck manually setting the filepath. Instead of ThisWorkbook.Path, you may need to do "\\servername\sharename\etc"

Comment: And on my initial response - since you're concatenating a "\", a file name and an extension, it's possible that something is misplaced or it's trying to access a folder that doesn't exist. I believe using workbook.path will return a file path such as "Z:\MyFolder" instead of "\\servername\sharename"

Comment: In any case, the first step is to split the responsibility of coming up with a filename from that of exporting a PDF - so you can inspect the concatenated value like any other local variable. Much easier than guessing, plus it leaves the instruction with nothing but a member call that takes a bunch of simple identifiers as arguments.

Comment: I see!! It works on other folder paths that happened to be shorter within the same drive. Is it possible that the path name is too long?

Comment: Side note, consider keeping named arguments together on the same line. `SomeArg:={expression}` should be all together, not `SomeArg:= _` and then the actual argument value/expression on another line. (or worse, `SomeArg _` and then `:=value` on another line)

Comment: if the full path is longer than 255 characters, you're asking for trouble, yes.

Comment: @Mathieu Guidon, thanks for your response, there are 171 characters in the path that it didn't work, vs 125 in the one it worked (3 folders shorter). I'm new to VBA, can you please elaborate regarding the name arguments? Preferably with an example, since it's easier for me to understand and digest!

Comment: I'm just nitpicking on the macro recorder's annoying habit of splitting named argument parts into multiple lines of code. I mean nothing more than what I wrote - `NamedArgument:=value` belongs all on the same line, without `_` line continuations. The macro recorder has a tendency to stick `_` newlines in the middle of named arguments, wherever "legal" to do so. That said, 125 is awfully close to 128, try appending a character to a working file's name, and then you'll know what the limit is. ...need less nested folders :)